# How to create a file using Nant script

Tags: nant

I want to create a file using nant script. Like mkdir any command is awailable in nant script for creating a text or doc file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`<touch>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/touch.html) task to create files (or update their timestamps). Using [`<echo>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/echo.html) you can output plain text to a file. [`<xmlpoke>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/xmlpoke.html) allows manipulating XML files.